# Getting node-gyp and node-sass error in Ubuntu OS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, npm, node-gyp

Get this issue when doing npm install.
How to solve this issue in Ubuntu OS 20.04. I found some related stuff to solve it but all is related to window OS. Found nothing to solve this issue on Ubuntu OS. i also do sudo apt-get install node-gyp but it also giving some error. this is command is used to solve the issue on windows install --global windows-build-tools but not for Ubuntu OS.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/bin/node /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.11.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:200:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-44-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/ali/Desktop/AlfaBolt/pakistanbooking_management_portal/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ali/.npm/_logs/2021-03-06T06_24_10_272Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I was unable to get python2 on my system, so I removed/replaced the packages requiring it (im my case it was @rails/webpacker and node-sass)

Answer (score 0):

Error message excerpt:

```
...
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
...
```

It looks like the error is saying that `python2` is required to install this package, though I'm not sure why a node module should require `python2` in 2021.

Just install `python2` using the standard way to install on your machine.

For example, on Ubuntu, you might install via Terminal with:

```sh
sudo apt install python2
```